# how to programmatically(python) execute terminal commands after invoking shell script(control will be under shell script))

Tags: python, shell, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

OS:Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
Python automation.

Hi, i am trying to do python automation in ubuntu, where i have to invoke a shell script programmatically, after invoking shell script i need to enter and execute terminal commands.

i am invoking shell script with below commands

```
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/murlee/CTS/android-cts/tools' -e 'bash -c \"./cts-tradefed; exec bash\"'")
```

*now i need help to enter and executing terminal commands after invoking the shell script

after invoking shell script my terminal will look like this
[Terminal_snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irQKG.png)

> "murlee@murlee-Lenovo-ideapad-100-14IBD:~/CTS/android-cts/tools$
> ./cts-tradefed
>
> Android CTS 6.0_r17 build: 3866870
>
> cts-tf >(here i have to enter commands and execute)"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an init script named `my-init.sh`

```
./cts-tradefed
```

Now call

```
import os
wd  = '/home/murlee/CTS/android-cts/tools'
cmd = "bash --init-file {0}".format('./my-init.sh')
os.system("gnome-terminal --working-directory='{0}' -e '{1}'").format(wd,cmd)
```

Comment: can you please tell me some specifics about my-init.sh.   i tried like your answer, but i dont have idea about where to keep the my-init.sh file. and please check my error and my-init.sh command also.   #!/bin/bash
$SCRIPT_PATH="/home/murali/CTS /android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed.sh"
exec "$SCRIPT_PATH",    Error:- There was an error creating the child process for this terminal, Failed to execute child process "{1}" (No such file or directory).